# Which entr[ies,y] should I modify in my .csproj file?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, csproj, target-framework

I'm having nothing but problems and confusion with version mismatches and incompatibilities between different versions of Windows CE/CF apps and the handheld devices on which they run.

I came to realize that perhaps I am confusing CF version with .NET runtime version.

In the IDE, the project in question's Framework Version (read-only property) says "v2.0"

For the project that DOES work (one one device, which as CF version 1.0.3316.00 installed, and perhaps version 1.1 of the .NET runtime), that value is 1.1, not 2.0

So I looked at the .csproj file to see what I might change to get the "v2.0" to change to "v1.1" (worth a try, anyway).

The .csproj has three "interesting" entries:

```
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5'"
```

Which one[s] (if any) should I change if I want to target .NET Runtime version 1.1 instead of 2.0?

What is "Schema Version"?

Should I change TargetFrameworkVersion to 1.1?

Should I change or remove "

### UPDATE

Well, it has become obvious via empirical observation that "TargetFrameworkVersion" is the element that changes the "*Framework Version*" property, however doing so (changing it to "v1.1") resulted in this:

[image]

...and so it seems as if I'm in a Catch-10648 situation ([22](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0048WQDIE) cubed), as version 1.1 is the only framework the .exe will run on...

I would rather [Catch Bull at 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004VW0S) or certainly sooner be the [Catcher in the Rye](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316769487), but beggars cannot be choosers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There never was a CF 1.1.  There was 1.0, 2.0, 3.5 and 3.9.  The only thing that matters in the project file is `TargetFrameworkVersion`.  Under Studio '08 that can be set to either `2.0` or `3.5`.  Nothing else is valid because no other compilers were installed with VS '08.  If you must compile for CF 1.0 (again, 1.1 never existed) you must use Studio 2003 or Studio 2005.

Though it's no relevant for you, for completeness sake, in VS 2013, the only valid value is `3.9`.

Comment: Okay, so something is certainly very rotten here in virtual Denmark (and I am close to Solvang at any rate): previously I was able to build and run .exes built on my machine, which has VS 2008 installed. I never built for CF 1. Now the only working .exe is a version-1 based one? If I was a little madder (in either sense of the word), I would mention the word "sabotage"